# How make redirect in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

I have domain.com/promo page and I made redirect from to this page from domain.com

```
My htaccess now looks 

Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /? [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=promo [L,QSA]
```

When I open pages like domain.com/about or domain.com/info in opens it, but when I try to open page domain.com/admin in opens domain.com page. How to make admin page working?

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1.*$ http://example.com/folder2/ [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect folder1 to folder2.

Answer (score 0):

> domain.com/admin in opens domain.com page. How to make admin page working?

Does /admin exist?

In default opencart, you do not need any redirect for /admin to load the admin panel.

If you want to *change* /admin, you:
1) rename the /admin folder via ftp, to something else.
2) Open admin/config.php and replace all "admin" entries with /newadminlocation

If you use vqmod, you will need to update the routing script in vqmod, as /admin is hardcoded.